# Is three levels of nesting too much for Firebase if I want fast updates?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: The structure]

What I do is query all the users for their current location so I can put them on a map. Unfortunately, even if I currently only have four test users, it takes quite a lot of time (sometimes up to 10 seconds) to have the results returned. Is this really a structure in need of flattening?

This is the Java code I'm using to get each user's CurrentLocation instance:

```
public void showLooksieUsersOnMap() {

        final Firebase myFirebase = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);


        Query query = myFirebase.child("users").orderByKey();


        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {

                String userId = arg0.getKey();

                Query query2 = myFirebase.child("users").child(userId)
                        .child("currentLocation");

                query2.keepSynced(true);

                query2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot arg0) {

                        String content = arg0.getKey();
                        Log.e("content ", content);

                        CurrentLocation currentLoc = arg0
                                .getValue(CurrentLocation.class);
                        Log.e("content loc ", currentLoc.toString());

                        userLocations.add(currentLoc);

                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLoc.getLat(),
                                currentLoc.getLon());

                        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_map))
                                .title("Hey there!"));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

I am trying to make the app seem faster by using query.keepSynced() and enabling data persistence (and it does work) but I've been led to believe that this is a workaround and in such cases it's better to flatten the data. Thing is, I wouldn't think it's so nested that it would make the operation take longer than 2 seconds to be performed, especially with only 4 users.

Thanks!

Comment: nesting doesn't make any lag as of their official documentation(till i have seen :D )

Comment: Nesting should definitely not give you any lags (apart from the obvious fact that you might be fetching a lot of data if you load the whole upper level). You should edit your question with the code you are using so people can better help you.

Comment: @Marcelo you're right, I'm adding the method that's querying the structure in my post!

Comment: As a comparison, our app has data structured in a similar fashion and we can query for and return 1000 nodes in something like .2 seconds;  It's almost instantaneous. In the code example, it looks like the code is 'double dipping' on the same data... aren't all of the users nodes going be returned by the initial query making the query2 read back in the data that's already been read? In query, arg0 key is the key and value is the currentLocation with child nodes of the coords?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit fresh with the Firebase Android API and I'm probably doing some idiotic stuff: since every user has a unique id autogenerated by Firebase, I first get their unique ids and then query for each user's location after getting each individual key. There has to be a better way to do it, which I don't know just yet. :) However, I have an update: today it suddenly started working MUCH faster for no reason at all: I didn't change anything in my app or Firebase structure and it's almost 20 times faster. Head scratcher, this one.